# iterating over formulas in purrr

Tags: r, linear-regression, purrr

I have a bunch of formulas, as strings, that I'd like to use, one at a time in a glm, preferably using tidyverse functions. Here's where I am at now.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

mtcars %>% dplyr::select(mpg:qsec) %>% colnames -> targcols
paste('vs ~ ', targcols) -> formulas
formulas

#> 'vs ~  mpg' 'vs ~  cyl' 'vs ~  disp' 'vs ~  hp' 'vs ~  drat' 'vs ~  wt' 'vs ~  qsec'
```

I can run a general linear model with any one of these formulas as

```
glm(as.formula(formulas[1]), family = 'binomial', data = mtcars) %>% glance

#>  null.deviance,  df.null,    logLik, AIC,    BIC,    deviance,   df.residual
#> 43.86011,    31,     -12.76667,  29.53334,   32.46481,   25.53334,   30
```

I'd like to run the glm with every possible formula in the list. I tried doing that as follows.

```
data.frame(formulas = formulas) %>%
    mutate(mod = map(formulas, function(fs){
        glm(as.formula(fs), family = 'binomial', data = mtcars)
    }))
```

But then I get the following error message:

> ```
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: invalid formula. Traceback:
>
> 1. data.frame(formulas = formulas) %>% mutate(mod = map(formulas,   .     function(fs) {  .         glm(as.formula(fs), family =
>        "binomial", data = mtcars)  .     }))
> 2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
> 3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
> 6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
> 7. withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
> 8. function_list[[k]](value)
> 9. mutate(., mod = map(formulas, function(fs) {  .     glm(as.formula(fs), family = "binomial", data = mtcars)  . }))
> 10. mutate.data.frame(., mod = map(formulas, function(fs) {   .     glm(as.formula(fs), family = "binomial", data = mtcars)   . }))
> 11. as.data.frame(mutate(tbl_df(.data), ...))
> 12. mutate(tbl_df(.data), ...)
> 13. mutate.tbl_df(tbl_df(.data), ...)
> 14. mutate_impl(.data, dots)
> ```

Could somebody tell me what I am missing here? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `data.frame()`; I'm not 100% sure *why* this doesn't work, but I think it's because data frames don't smoothly handle list columns.

Changing `data.frame` to `tibble` works for me. (It's from the `tibble` package, also exported via `dplyr`, so it should be available after `library("tidyverse")`)

You can shorten your code a little bit:

```
tibble(formulas) %>%
    mutate(mod = map(formulas, 
                      ~  glm(as.formula(.),
                             family = 'binomial', data = mtcars)))
```